# Which three-values would you choose for a "javascript enum"?

Tags: javascript, optimization

In JavaScript, I'm building something like tic-tac-toe (but more complex). Any given field can have three values: a black piece, a white piece or nothing. What would you use to represent these values? Considering you're gonna be passing around about 300+ at a time.

I was first thinking of 'B', 'W' and 'N'. Then I thought of 0, 1 and 2 and now I'm thinking about true, false and null. Which is the better option as far as JavaScript is concerned? Faster? More idiomatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not going to make a speed difference.

Personally, I'd go with 0,1,2.

In general, I'd avoid making a difference between undefined, null and false. That will just result in some mistakes in a conditional somewhere. In your case, undefined seems a pretty poor choice anyway, because the contents of the field are not undefined/unknown, it is well-defined to be empty.

Comment: "It is not going to make a speed difference." Can you back this up with a link explaining how integers are stored vs. true/false/null?

Comment: No. This is just an educated guess. I cannot think that there would be a material difference in how one would store boolean vs integer. And I have to think that something else is also going on in your code that would dwarf any such difference anyhow. Unless you notice a problem (profile it), I'd go with that. But maybe someone else can weigh in.

Answer (score 1):

As Thilo points out you'd want to avoid having multiple values that can make the statement `if(position)` evaluate `position` as true. I'd probably go with using `null` as the empty value, though, as it seems to make more sense to me.

For the other values, I'd definitely go with something that it's hard to mix up. Strings aren't great, because you're going to wind up using `B` instead of `W` *somewhere* along the line and get annoying errors, so `1` and `2` probably aren't bad options.

Another option, though, is to make your own "enum" for the purposes - just have `var black = new Object()` and `var white = new Object()` and use those. That way it's a bit more clear what you're referring to than just `1` and `2`. Much of a muchness, though.